# Mailchimp responsive HTML

Tags: responsive-design, mailchimp

Can anyone help with `HTML` fix for Mailchimp.

I have created a code, that is responsive, and when I test across devices, on some mobile (Android , Nexus phone) devices e-mail is, when opened zoomed in by default so I need to pinch zoom out so I can see whole newsletter, while it is good on iPhone (native mail app, gmail app) and on Android gmail app.

I have already added

`-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%`

and

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Specify `initial-scale=1.0` in the viewport meta tag.  For example:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```